# Amazon image upload issue: AmazonClientException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, amazon-s3

while trying to upload image to s3 with proper network speed its working fine. But in some device in between the upload if network is inconsistent or weak then the below error issue is coming. Please help me to resolve the error

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:441)
      at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
      at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4659)
      at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1752)
      at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.uploadSinglePartAndWaitForCompletion(UploadTask.java:219)
      at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:93)
      at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.UploadTask.call(UploadTask.java:49)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html), to mange the upload state, you can also upload in 2 steps, first upload to your server, then use the `TransferManager` for the S3 upload.

Comment: I am using transfer utility to upload images to amazon s3.

Comment: I am upload images in loop as-well.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, finally i kept maxErrorRetry count to 10. If uploading is not happening even after so i am removing the image from upload list and intimated to the user about network issue.

```
val configuration = ClientConfiguration()
configuration.maxErrorRetry = 10
configuration.maxConnections = 100
configuration.connectionTimeout = 0
configuration.socketTimeout = 0
val s3Client = AmazonS3Client(credentials,configuration)
```